# Pandas DataFrame construction from a list of OrderedDict: preserving columns order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ordereddictionary

pd.__version__ = 0.18.0

Suppose you have a *list* of  OrderedDict:

```
[OrderedDict([('SecurityCode', 'IDX.MSDENON'), ('DescriptionLong', 'MSCI Norway NR USD (EUR)'), ('DataSrc', 'BGN.COB'), ('Ticker', 'MSDENON Index'), ('LastRun', None)])]
```

if you construct a DataFrame from default constructor (or even with .from_dict() method)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)
```

it does not preserve column order:

```
      DataSrc  DescriptionLong    LastRun SecurityCode         Ticker  
   0  BGN.COB  MSCI Norway NR USD (EUR)    None  IDX.MSDENON  MSDENON Index
```

whereas :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=data[0].keys())

     SecurityCode           DescriptionLong  DataSrc         Ticker LastRun
  0  IDX.MSDENON  MSCI Norway NR USD (EUR)  BGN.COB  MSDENON Index    None
```

does perserve column order.

I read on StackOverflow that such bug was present in 0.11 but IMHO we shouldn't have to specify columns= option in default constructor. Am I missing something or it is a bug that calls for a report ?

EDIT:
A github issue on pydata/pandas repo has been created and accepted. It's a "bug" in default constructor, overriding OrderedDict column order in any cases. A correction has been planed for next major release (commit accepted for 0.18.2)

Comment: Still works like this in`0.18.1` you can update the issue or post a comment on github

Comment: What would you expect to happen if the second OrderedDict in the list has a different order?  Wouldn't it make sense to make you specify that you want to use the order of the first value?

Comment: those OrderedDict are created following SQL query, so order is defined once for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed an issue on DataFrame constructor (cf my EDIT).
I feel columns= option workaround is nicer (syntaxically more understandable) than hhbilly proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data[0], orient='index').T
```

Answer (score 0):

Roll your own....

```
newList = list()
columnNames = df.columns
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    newDict = OrderedDict()
    for key in columnNames:
        newDict[key] = row[key]
    newList.append(newDict)
```